# Returning values matching a sub item value from a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array that I want to search and return the '**names**' where the '**project_id**' equal a predefined value, for example from the array below:

```
array(2) 
{ 
    [0]=> array(28) 
        { 
            ["id"]=> int(3794) 
            ["name"]=> string(30) "Value #1" 
            ["milestone_id"]=> int(280) 
            ["project_id"]=> int(41) 
        } 
    [1]=> array(28) 
        { 
            ["id"]=> int(3795) 
            ["name"]=> string(30) "Value #2" 
            ["milestone_id"]=> int(261) 
            ["project_id"]=> int(41) 
        }
    [2]=> array(28) 
        { 
            ["id"]=> int(37966) 
            ["name"]=> string(30) "Value #3" 
            ["milestone_id"]=> int(250) 
            ["project_id"]=> int(40) 
        }
    [3]=> array(28) 
        { 
            ["id"]=> int(3797) 
            ["name"]=> string(30) "Value #4" 
            ["milestone_id"]=> int(250) 
            ["project_id"]=> int(42) 
        }
    [4]=> array(28) 
        { 
            ["id"]=> int(3798) 
            ["name"]=> string(30) "Value #5" 
            ["milestone_id"]=> int(280) 
            ["project_id"]=> int(41) 
        }           
}
```

I would like to return all of the `names` for any of the records that have the `project_id` of **41** - in this case:

```
Value #1
Value #2
Value #5
```

To be honest, I'm new to PHP, and I've been stumbling around the interwebs trying to make some sense of various code snippets & instructions - none of which seem to do what I am after without significant fettling which I unfortunately lack the knowhow to do so any help would really be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Just iterate all the subarrays

Comment: In the simplest form, you would simply iterate over the array in a simple loop, and inside check whether the project_id of the current item equals 41 - and if so, output whatever else you like from the current item. This is quite a trivial thing, if you read up on the basics of data structures and loops ... so at least show us some of your attempts.

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with [array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($array, function($row) {
    return $row['project_id'] == 41;
});
```

This will leave you with a `$filteredArray` holding all the items with project_id == 41.

Now you can iterate over these values, and print out the names, or what you want to do:

```
foreach ($filteredArray as $row) {
    echo $row['name'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or, if you just want an an array, you can do this with [array_column](http://php.net/array_column)

```
array_column($filteredArray, 'name');
```

Or simply (in one step)

```
$names = array_column(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        function($row) {
            return $row['project_id'] == 41;
        }
    ),
    'name'
);
```

Which leaves you with the final array

```
$names Array (
    (string) "Value #1"
    (string) "Value #2"
    (string) "Value #3"
)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much - you saved my sanity!

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the sub arrays and look for the specific condition like this

```
     $customArray = array();
     foreach($outerArry as $subArray){

       if($subArray["project_id"]==41){

         $customArray[] = $subArray;
         }  
      }
      print_r($customArray);
```